Possession and Buffs
How buffs interact with Possession RAW? Can I assume body-related buffs are attached to the vessel while mind-related and soul-related buffs are attached to the possessor?
So for the simplest of examples:

Bull's Strength cast while possessing vessel will stay on the vessel when Possession ends.
Fox's Cunning cast while possessing vessel will stay on the possessor when Possession ends.

Am I interpreting this correctly?

See this Q&A. Does that answer your question? I suspect its as close to RAW on this as you'll get, but am not sure if it would be a duplicate, as the questions differ slightly, even if the answers seem to cover the same ground.

Probably as close to an answer to the question as you can get, but duplicate answers don't mean the questions are duplicates.

I am quoting at length from @ShadowKras' answer, which has an in-depth treatment of the issue, even though it is in response to a slightly different question:
Physical effects will affect the vessel's body, and stick with it

Most poisons and diseases affect a creature's body, not their mind. So, if you are possessing a creature and they are afflicted with any disease or poison, that will affect you while you are in the host, but will not affect you when you get out.
When possessing a creature, the caster (possessor), is currently using the creature's physical ability scores and not their own, so any damage or drain caused should affect you while you are using the host, and reduce any checks that depend on that ability. If the damage/drain is caused on strength, dexterity or constitution, it will affect whoever is in control of the body.

The same logic applies to spell-buffs like bull's strength.
Mental effects affect the mind that was targeted, so might travel

Unlike other effects (Magic Jar), the host's soul is not ejected from her body when using Possession, and mental effects (like charms) are clarified in Occult Adventures:

Compulsion and charm effects move with the mind or soul of the creature originally targeted. For example, if you cast mind swap on a dominated creature, the domination effect remains active but transfers with the originally dominated mind to its new host body, and a dominated creature capable of possession could possess another creature while still remaining dominated.
If the host’s mind or soul is not displaced from the body, a dominating creature can still telepathically interact with its now-possessed target, even though the target is helpless within its own hijacked body. The dominating creature can even command the target to explain what the host body is doing, if the host has access to its senses.
When both the host creature and a possessing creature occupy a body at the same time, a charm or compulsion effect can target either one.

It is worth reading all that page for clarifications about how Possession and similar effects work, by the way.
As GM, if the player, or an NPC/monster targeting a PC, decides to cast Feeblemind on the "bugbear in front of me", the magic will target the creature that is the owner of the body, unless the caster has some way to know that two creatures are inside that body and decides to specifically call out which one they want to affect with the spell.
This was called out in the Haunted Heroes Handbook, and makes a lot of sense in that context, as you are dealing with ghost or demonic possession, and the very first thing you have to identify, is that the creature is actually possessed by another entity.

If both the host creature and a possessing creature occupy the same body at the same time, charms and compulsions automatically target the host creature’s mind unless the caster is aware the creature is being possessed (letting the caster choose to target either the host or the possessor).

As for any other mental effect, like the Blue Whinnis poison or ability damage/drain to mental scores, I would apply it to both creatures, as they are both conscious inside the body and should be affected equally by anything that hurts their minds.

The same logic would apply to buff spells like Fox's Cunning targeting the host creature. So for mind-affecting spells, under RAW the caster needs to pick the possessor, if they want the spell to stick to them, otherwise it will affect the hosts mind (even though that is not controlling the body at the time, so charms will be futile unless you figure out there is someone possessing the target, and you need to target them; likewise would the fox's cunning not make the possessor smarter by default). If they pick the possessor, it will be on the possessor and travel. If they don't it will be on the vessel and not travel.
The last sentence in the quoted section by @ShadowKras is their take on what to do for effects that cannot pick a target (poisons etc.). That one is not spelled out in the rules, so how you handle those cases is undefined and needs a DM call.
